# How do I add items from from the user module to a menu?

Tags: routes, navigation

How do I add the core user module links such as *My account* and *Log out* to another menu?

Answer (score 1):

The *My Account* and *Log Out* links are defined in `core/modules/user/user.links.menu.yml`

```yml
user.page:
  title: 'My account'
  weight: -10
  route_name: user.page
  menu_name: account
user.logout:
  weight: 10
  menu_name: account
  class: Drupal\user\Plugin\Menu\LoginLogoutMenuLink
```

As you can see they are hardcoded to the `account` menu. With this in mind, really the best thing to do is simply place both menus next to each other on the Block Overview page. This works for probably 95% of use cases. Your CSS should be written in a way to support that. For the other 5%, you could go as far as to piggyback your own links in a custom module. If you were to do so, it would/could look something like this:

`my_module.info.yml`

```
type: module
name: 'My Module'
description: 'Copy user links.'
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
package: 'User'
dependencies:
  - user:user
```

`my_module.links.menu.yml`

```
my_module.user_page:
  title: 'My account'
  weight: -10
  route_name: user.page
  menu_name: YOUR_MENU_ID
my_module.user_logout:
  weight: 10
  menu_name: YOUR_MENU_ID
  class: Drupal\user\Plugin\Menu\LoginLogoutMenuLink
```